# Delete latest git commit only in remote?

Tags: git, github, push, commit

The commit sequence for my remote repo looks like

A > B > C > D

where commit D is a garbage commit that I don't want, and is not present in my local `log` (it was generated by github pages settings which i no longer need).  The commit sequence for local looks like

A > B > C > E

where E is a commit more recent than D that I'm trying to push.

How can I simply delete commit D from remote and push commit E? I can't seem to find an answer that doesn't also alter the local commit.

Comment: Do a new clone in a separate directory, drop the commit, force push.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Why not just force push?

Comment: Uh that's right, I misread your question - I thought history had diverged in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use force push:

```
git push -f
```

Local doesn't change, remote sync with local.

Comment: What would this actually do in this situation?

Comment: remote will be the same as your local